# CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm have initialised a string array,then inside a foreach loop I try to execute a linq query and store the result of the query to the string array that was initialised.

I tried ToList() and such but it does'nt work

```
public class TierImaegeDefinitionDTO
        {
            public string Tier { get; set; }
            public string[] ImageDefinition { get; set; }
        }
foreach (var tierVal in tierList)
{
                String tier = tierVal.Tier;
                 var imageDefinitionList = (from p in _context.Product
                                            join ti in _context.TierImageMap 
                                            on p.Id equals ti.ProductId join t 
                                            in _context.Tiers on ti.TierType 
                                            equals t.Id
                                           where (p.Id == ProductId) && 
                                           (t.TierType == tier)
                                             select new
                                           {
                                               ti.ImageName,

                                           }).ToList().Distinct();
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                tierVal.ImageDefinition = imageDefinitionList;//getting error in this line
            }
```

Comment: Nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string[]'"_ means that CLR cannot implicitly convert `imageDefinitionList` variable of type `IEnumerable<SomeAnonymousType>` to `string[]` variable to be able to assign it to `tierVal.ImageDefinition`

Answer (score 2):

ImageDefinition is an array of string[]. ToList() will return List<T>, and Distinct will return IEnumerable<T>. You need to change your call so that it ends with

```
.Distinct().ToArray()
```

Another problem is that you are selecting an object, so your .ToList() is actually returning List<anonymous type>. Instead, you can just select ti.ImageName

```
var imageDefinitionList = 
    (from p in _context.Product 
        join ti in _context.TierImageMap on p.Id equals ti.ProductId 
        join t in _context.Tiers on ti.TierType equals t.Id 
        where (p.Id == ProductId) && (t.TierType == tier) 
        select ti.ImageName
    ).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: @Adithya welcome to StackOverflow. The best way to say thank you here is to mark the answer that helped you as accepted. If you don't know how to do it have a look [at this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)